# Strange behaviour with setting navigationBar.tintColor in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, swift4

I am experiencing an unexpected behaviour with setting `UINavigationBar.tintColor` in `viewDidLoad()`.

I have two ViewControllers `ViewController` and `SecondViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. A `UIButton` is triggering the segue from `ViewController` to `SecondViewController`. Both ViewControllers have set a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom `UIImage`.

In my `SecondViewController` i want to have a different tintColor of my navigationbar.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = nil
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 200/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Storyboard looks like this:

[image: Storyboard]

When the transition from `ViewController` to `SecondViewController` is happening, the `UIBarButtonItem` on the right side set is jiggling a bit. I was expecting the item to change its color but not to jiggle in any way.

Does anyone have suggestions for this behaviour?

(I also tried to set the tintColor in `viewWillAppear` but this does not solve the problem. If i set the the tintColor in `viewDidAppear` everything is fine. But this is too late for my use case.)

If you need further informations give suggestions let me know i will provide any information needed.

GIF showing this problem:

[image]

Comment: @FaysalAhmed That does the trick. Thank you! Can you explain why this solutions is working?

Comment: tried to explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change color in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.
This is the small trick to solve this type of problem.

Learn more from Apple developer site: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews